# add url match in django

Tags: django, apache, url

my site is build on django.
i want to open a folder "files" on same server to place other files accessed from not he django site.

```
mysite.com
mysite.com/files
```

however when I try to access that folder, django says

> "The current URL, files, didn't match any of these."

meaning that that folder is not defined in url patterns, which i dont need for Django site.

how I can bypass this Django url matcher, and access any custom url on my server without Django site?

Comment: how are you hosting django (apache/modwsgi, gunicorn, nginx, etc.?)  In general, in the host server, you should be able to put mysite.com/files first and that will match before the bit that passed control onto django's URL matcher

Comment: it is hosted apache/modwsgi. is it possible to put url priority somehow, as you say?

Comment: well you need to specify the files you want to serve in the conf file.I think this may help http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Django at all. You just need an Alias directive in your Apache site configuration.

```
Alias /files/ /path/to/mysite.com/files/
```